# Vaadin23 navigate is not working in BeforeEnterEvent

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I try to check if specific parameters of a url are valid. If they aren't the user should be navigated to a different route. It's important that it's a navigate and not a redirect.

When i try to use `UI.getCurrent().navigate()` in der BeforeEnterEvent i'm experiencing some weird issues.

Some workarround i found is when i call the navigate method in the `UI.getCurrent().access()` function. Since then the code will be executed at a later point.

```java
UI.getCurrent().access(() -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(""));
```

So i'm wondering if this is the right way to do this because this seems pretty bad. Is there a better event to call the navigate method?

Comment: Why not use `BeforeEnterEvent.forwardTo()`?

Comment: @TarekOraby I didnt know about this one thank you